# How to Step through the code attaching an event listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

The event listener (onClick event) never gets attached.

I'm trying to Step Through the code that *attaches* it but Chrome Dev Tools won't let me put a break point on the first or second lines. (.ready... and .on(click...

MyPage.html  has:

```
<script src="scripts/expander.js" ></script> 
</body>
```

expander.js  is:

```
/* expander control */
$().ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.js-expander', function(e){
    var e =  e || event, 
        $el = $(this), 
        $content;

    e.preventDefault();

    $content = $el.parent().next('.js-expander-content')
    if ($content.length == 0)
      $content = $el.parent().parent().next('.js-expander-content')
      if ($content.length == 0)
        $content = $el.siblings('.js-expander-content');

    $content.slideToggle(150);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `debugger;` where you want the breakpoint in the code and run it.That will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put a breakpoint in javascript. You can put a debugger between your first and second line.